# Need to create a folder in remote server usint ant

Tags: ant, scp

using ant scp i can able to copy a file from local system(windows) to server(linux).so what i need is i want to create a folder by the system date at specified directory in linux system using ant and copy the file to the folder which created..

this is my ant script:

```
<sshexec host="hostname:22" username="****" trust="true"
     password="fcubs" 
     command="mkdir $/home/desktop/<folder to be creted here>"/>
   <scp todir="username@hostname:/home/desktop" password="*****" trust="true">
      <fileset dir="D:\kkk"/>
   </scp>
```

pls help me 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use such linux command which creates directory:

```
export ATD=`date '+%h-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S'` && cd /path/to/specified/dir && mkdir $ATD && cd $ATD
```

it will create dir (for example) "**Nov-14-2012_17:41:02**" in the dir /path/to/specified/dir and will cd to it.

after executing this command you can simply copy your file to the directory.